# Start 3rd party activity, later destroy it to return to own activity

Tags: android

Out of my Activity ("A") I want to start a 3rd party App's Launcher Activity. This 3rd party Activity ("B") eventually pastes some content to clipboard.

I have an OnPrimaryClipChangedListener added to the ClipboardManager inside A and I want to return to A when the clipboard changed inside B.

The code inside MainActivity (Activity "A"):

```
public void buttonClicked(View v) {

    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("third.party.package");
    Log.d(TAG,intent.toString());
    startActivity(intent);

    final ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    cm.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            if (cm.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                ClipData data = cm.getPrimaryClip();
                String str = data.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                if (str.matches("^\\d{6}$")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("some.identifier", str);
                    Log.d(TAG,intent.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cm.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The listener works, proven by the Toast which shows the content of clipboard.

I presume the Activity Stack to be A > B after starting B. And as I understand the docs for

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

the startActivity() inside my listener should start a new instance of A. But instead of putting it on top of the stack (A > B > A) it should pop every activity on top of A so in this case the stack consists only of A.

But instead I see the Toast with Activity B being in foreground (not A).

Any suggests?

Comment: You calling MainActivity from MainActivity

Comment: @aksacha Yeah, I know. Any ideas how I can get the behaviour I want?